# How to compare images on multiple pictureboxes if one of the image is same on those before inserting into database using c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have 5 picture boxes and would like to add images on them.

I am looking for to check the images of those if any one of the image is same on them then not to insert just display alert message else it gets inserted into database

Help appreciate!

Comment: The answer would depend on if you mean "pixel for pixel identical" or "visually similar". Note that if you open a JPG and save it as a different filename*, rather than copying the file, the won't be pixel-for-pixel identical because of the lossy compression used. *It might depend on the software though, since some software might be smart enough to realise you haven't made any changes and thus write the same file verbatim.

Comment: What do you mean is the same ? Should they have all the pixels with the same values ? Or is the same subject ?

Comment: if they have pixels with the same values

Comment: means identical images

Comment: Then just convert them to byte array and check if they are identical. Take care that 2 images acquired with a steady camera one after another will be not be identical(noise on the sensor will create different pixel values) , only copied and pasted files will result as the same with this method, or artificial image created by settings value of the single pixels.

Comment: Still unclear; he may mean 'coming from the same file'..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want perform a pixel to pixel between `img1` and `img2`, you can do this:

```
    public byte[] ToByteArray(Image image, ImageFormat format)
    {
         using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
         {
             image.Save(ms, format);
             return ms.ToArray();
         }
    }

    public bool ImageEquals(Image img1, Image img2)
    {
        var array1 = ToByteArray(img1, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        var array2 = ToByteArray(img2, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return array1.SequenceEqual(array2);
    }
```

Than you can add them to your DB, keep in mind that usually they are not stored directly in the DB (even if could be possible using the BLOB field type) but they are stored as a link to the file.